# Splunk: combine fields from multiple lines

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

### Context

Say I have logs structured this way

```sh
TID: http-incoming-972453 >> POST /token HTTP/1.1 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} # I want this
TID: http-incoming-972453 >> Accept: application/json {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-incoming-972453 >> Host: some.organization.com {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
.....
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> Host: some.other.organization.intra:9444 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> Connection: Keep-Alive {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 >> User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: http-outgoing-8816 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
.....
TID: http-incoming-972453 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} # with this
TID: http-incoming-972453 << X-Frame-Options: DENY {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
.....
```

and I have tuned `props.conf` so that

```sh
TID: http-incoming-972453 >> POST /token HTTP/1.1 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
```

ends up indexed with the following fields

- **httpRequestId**: `972453`
- **ressourceName**: `/token`

and

```sh
TID: http-incoming-972453 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
```

with

- **httpRequestId**: `972453`
- **httpStatus**: `200`

I am looking for a way to count requests, aggregated by *httpStatus* and *ressourceName* using *httpRequestId* as a join

### Attempts

Since information about `ressourceName` and `httpStatus` occur on different events, I thought of using a **join**. This does not give any results

```sql
index=* role="gw" httpAction="incoming" | join type=outer httpRequestId [fields ressourceName,httpStatus] | stats count by ressourceName,httpStatus
```

While reading Splunk documentation, I also came across `selfjoin`, results of which where only partial

```sql
index=* role="gw" httpAction="incoming" | selfjoin httpRequestId | stats count by ressourceName,httpStatus
```

How can I combine fields from multiple events to end up with something like

```
/somewhere           200         30
/somewhere           403         1
/somewhere/else      200         15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of join was incorrect.  The subsearch must be a valid search, starting with "search" or "|".

Try the `stats` command.

```
index=foo role=gw httpAction="Incoming
| stats values(*) as * by httpRequestId
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at using the transaction command.

```
index=* role="gw" httpAction="incoming" | transaction httpRequestId | stars count by ressourceName,httpStatus
```

Depending on the volume of data you want to analyse and timeframes, transaction or join would be sufficient.